# How to check every element of list recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I am currently trying to code a function recursively but I am stuck on the base case. Basically, my problem is that I don't know how to create the base case since I don't know how to check every element of the list recursively. If I was to use a for loop, it would go something like

```
for i in range(len(A)):
```

where `A` is a list. How would I changed that into recursion?

Edit: I am now aware that I gave too little details. Lets say I have a list of numbers `[5,6,-1,7,-3]` I want my output to be just the positive numbers, so by the code it would be `[5,6,3]`. Now my problem is that I can easily do this using a `for` loop to check every element of the list, but I want to do it recursively and I don't know how to do that for lists. I hope It is clearer now/makes sense.

Comment: We just can't tell you anything without more details... Please clarify what you are trying to do exactly;

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Can you think of a way to *describe* the problem recursively? What happened when you tried putting `thinking about problems recursively` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=thinking+about+problems+recursively)?

Comment: You want to write code that breaks the problem down into simpler problems, and stops when it reaches a problem that can't be broken down any more. What's the simplest example of an input list you can think of? What's a way to move in that direction, given the ability to check a single element?

Comment: for i in A: is enough to iterate through all the elements in the list 'A'

Comment: @ThierryLathille  I hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

The base case is when then list element is not a nested list, like follows:

```
def visit_list_rec(x):
    # base case, we found a non-list element
    if type(x) != list:
        print(x)
        return

    # recursive step, visit each child
    for element in x:
        visit_list_rec(element)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    visit_list_rec(["this", "is", ["a", ["nested", "list"]]])
```

Comment: `not isinstance(x, list)` would probably be a bit better than `type(x) != list`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. The base case is when there are no more numbers left to check.

```
def positive_vals(nums, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    if not nums:
        return result
    else:
        if nums[0] > 0:
            result.append(nums[0])
        return positive_vals(nums[1:], result)


numbers = [5, 6, -1, 7, -3]
print(positive_vals(numbers))  # -> [5, 6, 7]
```